# Find a canonical form through orthogonal transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I need to find a canonical form through orthogonal transformation, the problem is, that the equation given to me doesn't make sense:

$$4x_1^2+4x_2^2+x_3^2-2x_1x_2-2\sqrt{3}x_2x_3 $$
The matrix for this form is:
\begin{pmatrix}
4 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 4 & -\sqrt{3}\\
0 &-\sqrt{3} & 1
\end{pmatrix}

This matrix are correct? So the equation to find eigenvalues looks like this: $-^3+9^2−20+3=0$. How to solve equation like this? I have such roots [image] as I have to find transformation matrix

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: use https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+-x%5E3%2B9x2%E2%88%9220x%2B3%3D0 .

Comment: Yes, your matrix is correct. Your equation to find the eigenvalues also is correct. The eigenvalues do not have a nice closed form.

Comment: You can use Gauss method

Comment: What methods can you use? Only diagonalisation or also Gauss method?

Comment: I can use any method

Comment: @Юля Then try Gauss-Lagrange algorithm

Comment: it doesn't work for this matrix or I don't understand something

Comment: @Юля I think it works, why shouldn't?

Answer (score 1):

Your quadratic form $$4x_1^2+4x_2^2+x_3^2-2x_1x_2-2\sqrt{3}x_2x_3 $$ can be written as
$$v^{\top}Qv
=
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{array}
\right)^{\top}\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 4 & -1 & 0 \\
 -1 & 4 & -\sqrt{3} \\
 0 & -\sqrt{3} & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3
\end{array}
\right).$$

If we introduce a basis change in order to express this at its
easier viewpoint one choose the $Q$ eigenvectors.
The next matrix shows them in the columns
$$S=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0.55415 & 0.82474 & 0.11279 \\
 -0.77451 & 0.46119 & 0.43294 \\
 0.30505 & -0.32727 & 0.89434 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Now, manipulate as
\begin{eqnarray*}
v^{\top}Qv&=&(SS^{-1}v)^{\top}QSS^{-1}v\\
&=&(S^{-1}v)^{\top}\ (S^{\top}QS)\ S^{-1}v\\
\end{eqnarray*}
to achieve the effect of writing your quadratic form into the form
$$v^{\top}Qv=q_1y_1^2+q_2y_2^2+q_3y_3^2,$$
where
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\y_2\\y_3
\end{array}
\right)=S^{-1}v$$
are the components of $v$ in the new basis.
It easy to calculate that $S^{\top}QS$ would be the diagonal matrix
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 q_1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & q_2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & q_3 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

Observe that $S^{-1}QS$ gives the diagonalization of $Q$
which has the eigenvalues in the principal diagonal as
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 5.3977 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 3.4408 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0.16153 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$

If instead of choosing the eigenvectors suggested by Wolfram-Alpha
you use a normalization of them then the matrix $S$ would be orthogonal.